# how to pass multiple labels through ContentPage

Tags: xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am looking for help setting the code behind to pass multiple Labels using the next button. Basically I want to have a label set when the page is opened, press the next button and have a new label replace the current one (without setting new content pages). I a beginner working in Xamarin.Forms and I am not really understanding the data binding process... If anyone has a good reference (other than the Microsoft Website) that would help as well. Pretty sure the code below will not do anything yet... Thanks in advance :)

this is the ContentPage:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label Text="{Binding TitleText}" />
        <ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <StackLayout>
                <Label Text="{Binding EngText}" />

                <Label Text="{Binding ItText}" />

            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

This is what I started for the code behind:

''''''

```
namespace MVVM2
{
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    List<MainPage> Contacts { get; set; }
    int ndx = 0;

    public string TitleText { get; set; }
    public string EngText { get; set; }
    public string ItText { get; set; }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Contacts = new List<MainPage>();

        // repeat this for as many contacts as you need
        Contacts.Add(new MainPage
        {
            TitleText = "Title1",
            EngText = "EngText1",
            ItText = "ItText1"
        });

        Contacts.Add(new MainPage
        {
            TitleText = "Title2",
            EngText = "EngText2",
            ItText = "ItText2"
        });

        Contacts.Add(new MainPage
        {
            TitleText = "Title3",
            EngText = "EngText3",
            ItText = "ItText3"
        });

        // display the first contact
        BindingContext = Contacts[ndx];
    }

    private void OnNavigateButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // increment your index
        ndx++;

        // check that we haven't gone too far
        if (ndx < Contacts.Count)
        {
            BindingContext = Contacts[ndx]; 
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Let's sort out the model class first. What is Contact for? Are there more text coming, like MathText, PhyText?

Comment: It would just be the three labels and an image between the EngText and ItText. Contact was part of the example I had taken from and will be changed to a more fitting work like Longsword or Dagger depending on the section I am completing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you just want to display different text when the button is clicked, you don't need to navigate to a new page

first, create a `List` to hold your buttons and a variable to keep track of which one is displayed.  These two lines should be in the body of your class but NOT inside any specific method

```
List<Contact> contacts { get; set; }
int ndx = 0;
```

then in your constructor setup your data

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
 
    contacts = new List<Contact>();

    // repeat this for as many contacts as you need
    contacts.Add(new Contact { 
        TitleText = "Title1",
        EngText = "EngText1",
        ItText = "ItText1"});
   
    // display the first contact
    BindingContext = contacts[ndx];
}
```

finally, handle the button click

```
async void OnNavigateButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // increment your index
   ndx++;

   // check that we haven't gone too far
   if (ndx < contacts.Count) {
     BindingContext = contacts[ndx];
   }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jason, It seems like my bindings are not picking up the labels from the code-behind. Am I missing something?

Comment: Try moving the Contact class so it’s not nested inside of your page class

Comment: Hey Jason, I figured out the issue... the page wont initialize... Is there a way to show you what I have done?

Comment: Yes, edit your post to include any additional info or code

Comment: I have no idea what the current problem you're trying to solve is.